# Netbeans calling SQL commands from a text file

Tags: netbeans, javadb

I want to get Netbeans to look at a text file where I have written loads of SQL commands to be executed. I'm sure it can be done, but searched and cannot find how.

I am using Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2, OS X ML, Java DB and writing in Java.

Comment: do you have a `sql` script file?

Comment: I have a .txt file with sql commands inside. Is that not all I need?

Comment: so you basically want some batch operations on your database?

Comment: Exactly what I'm after.

Comment: So whats the problem go ahead and create a `java` code which can read commands from your file and execute those commands.

Comment: I'm sure you can get Netbeans to load a text file in - without me having to write code to do it - but cannot find how to do this in Netbeans.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25018/discussion-between-suku-and-john-vasiliou)